# Input lose focus when writing

Tags: reactjs

I'm a new user of ReactJS, so I can't figured out how to solve my issue.

I have an input in a Popup. When this popup is displayed and when I'm writing in the input, it lost the focus.
I made some searches and found that it's maybe because the popup is displayed in the render() method. So I think it's rendered each time it's refreshed. But I don't know how I could put the popup display outside the render()

I put console.log in render() method and I lost focus each time my console.log are displayed.

My code :

```
render() {
let {imageLoading, videoLoading} = this.state;
    let {imagePreviewUrl} = this.state;
    let mediaPreview = null;
    let imagePreview = null;
    let videoPreview = null;
    let popup = null;
    let handleSubmit = null;
    let resetForm = null;
    Popup.close();
    if (imagePreviewUrl) {
        console.log('BDeGDE');
        mediaPreview = (
            <div>
                <img className={"img-fluid"} src={imagePreviewUrl} />
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <p>Vous pouvez ajouter un descriptif à votre photo :</p>
                <input style={{width: "100%"}} type={"text"} id={"text_descriptif_image"}/>
            </div>
        );
        handleSubmit = this._handleSubmit;
        resetForm = this._resetForm;
    }

    if (this.props._isAddingMedia) {
        console.log('EEDNE');
        if (mediaPreview) {
            popup = Popup.register({
                content: mediaPreview,
                buttons: {
                    left: [{
                        text: 'ANNULER',
                        className: 'btn btn-color-2 btn-outline-secondary btn-sm mr-2 float-left',
                        action: function () {
                            resetForm();
                            Popup.close();
                        }
                    }],
                    right: [{
                        text: 'ENVOYER',
                        className: 'btn btn-color-3 btn-sm float-right',
                        action: function () {
                            handleSubmit();
                            resetForm();
                            Popup.close();
                        }
                    }]
                }
            });
            Popup.queue(popup);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={"text-left"}>
                <i onClick={this._handleImageAdd} className="mr-2 fa fa-picture-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i onClick={this._handleVideoAdd} className="fa fa-video-camera fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>

            <form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}>
                <input type="file" onChange={this._handleImageChange} accept="image/*" ref="fileImageUploader" style={{display: "none"}}/>
                <input type="file" onChange={this._handleVideoChange} accept="video/*" ref="fileVideoUploader" style={{display: "none"}}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wrong with your state, You must change them with "setState". And when You have state you can use them as a alternatives for variables, because in React working with them is much easier.As a guid You can read this:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781

And if after that You still got the same issue try to separate Popup and the component where You want to execute that (I mean create component that will have only Popup) and call that component in your current component.If You know the difference between state and props you can do that very well! If not, just look the documentation.Sorry I can't post the code,because I afraid to do many issues that will confuse You.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Add popup as a child component and render it in render return statement. To know how to create child components refer https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: I did this but I lost the focus again. And I figured out that it was because of the Popup.close(); on top, under the variable declaration. So I tried to comment this line, the input keep the focus but when I click on cancel button, the Popup.close(); don't work here... So the popup stay display